# What's wrong with this code? Replacing blank cells in excel to 0 in Python

Tags: python, excel, loops

I have asked this question and I would to seek an opinion from other experts as well on how to resolve the issue. Basically, what the script does is it checks the Column A from Source.xlsx and if the value matches, the value in Column Count will be written to Column Count of Test.xlsx. If the value of Column Count in Source.xlsx is blank, the script should write 0 in Column Count of Test.xlsx. I was advised to use this code daily_data.fillna(0, inplace=True) but so far it has no errors however it doesn't convert the blank values in Column Count of Test.xlsx to 0.

Your opinion or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl

daily_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Test.xlsx')
master_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Source.xlsx')

daily_sheet = daily_data['WorkSheet']
master_sheet = master_data['WorkSheet']

for i in daily_sheet.iter_rows():
Column_A = i[0].value
row_number = i[0].row
for j in master_sheet.iter_rows():
    if j[0].value == Column_A:
        daily_sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=6).value = j[1].value
        
        #print(j[1].value)

daily_data.save('C:/Test.xlsx')
daily_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Test.xlsx')
daily_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: If it's an empty string and not a NaN value, try replacing it (immediately to 0, not NaN as they are in the examples) with this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-replace-blank-values-with-nan/

Comment: @Notus_Panda, thank you for the suggestion. I'll try it out and let you know the results. Appreciate it.